# Convert A Ghost Image File Into A VMware Disk Image File?

Tags: vmware-workstation, file-conversion, norton-ghost

I am trying to convert a Ghost image file (.gho) to a VMware disk image file (.vdmk). I am using this command:

```
ghost32 -clone,mode=restore,src=my.gho,dst=myimage.vmdk -batch -sure
```

I get the following error:

> 'Ghost32' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.

I think I must go to location of image first, and then convert file but I don't know how.

Comment: ghost32 is not in your path statement.  locate the actually ghost32.exe file.  for example c:\folder\subfolder\ghost32.exe and then the rest.

Answer (score 2):

As you see, the command `Ghost32` is not recognized.

**What does that mean?**
That means, that in your path, the application `ghost32` couldn't be found.

So you have to change to the right directory. To do that, just type in:

```
cd C:/Path/To/The/Ghost32.exe
```

`cd` means change directory.

Comment: thank you very match. I do this guide and now I have this error:D:\>ghost32.exe-clone,mode=restore,src="d:\tdi\tdi.gho",dst="d:\myimage.vmdk"-patch -sure         ABORT:11030, invalid destination drive

Comment: You have the Error "-"?

Comment: @jafar Which version of Ghost are you using? You need at least 11.5 to deal with VMDKs.

Comment: thank you very match Friends. I used Ghost version 11.5 and it worked. but near end of convert I receive this error: ABORT 651,Unable to locate next Span. operation aborted at user request.

Comment: I clear -sure from end of instruction but it didn't work again. then I rename my file to original name (create with norton ghost) and it worked. but I have new problem! when I load this file with VMWare the windows doesn't work. in first of windows loading I see blue screen and windows is reset. what should I do? please help me again.